# Loop over button function call [kotlin]

Tags: android, button, kotlin, soundpool

I tried to code my first app.

Layout:

3 buttons to control 3 audio streams, 1 button to load an audio stream from a file.

Expected behaviour:

- When pressing the load button, followed by any of the other three (control) buttons, a file pick dialog shall appear and the selected audio file will be "allocated" to the respective control button.
- When pressing on an allocated control button and if the assigned sound is longer than 20 seconds, the button color shall change through a new xml allocation and the stream shall be played once. When the stream is already playing, the play mode for that stream shall change to infinite loop. Another press will lead to stopping the audio stream.

Approach:
The control buttons have a reference inside the xml file to a "ControlOnClick" function that shall be called inside the main activity. The load button has a reference to "pickOnClick" which only changes a status variable.

Status:
File picking is excluded at the moment to keep complexity low. There is a hardcoded placeholder for that.

Question: How can I loop over all three buttons without the need of copy/paste a switch case for each button inside "ControlOnClick"?

Layout activity_main.xml snippet:

```
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:onClick="ControlOnClick"
        android:text="Empty"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="456dp"
        android:onClick="pickOnClick"
        android:text="Load audio"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

and the button/sound duration functions in main activity.kt:

```
    fun pickOnClick(v: View){
        // load button was pressed
        loadactive=true
    }

   fun ControlOnClick(v: View) {
        when (v.id) {
            // button1 was pressed
            R.id.button1 -> {
                if (loadactive == true) {
                    // load sound file if load button was pressed before, rename button1 and reset
                    sound1 = soundPool.load(this, meldeath1, 1)
                    // decide if it is a short or long clip
                    var resID = getResources().getIdentifier("meldeath1", "raw", getPackageName())
                    shortcliparray[1]=getSoundDuration(resID)
                    button1.text = "meldeath1"
                    if (shortcliparray[1]==false) {
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_notplaying)
                    }
                    loadactive = false
                } else {
                    // play, loop or stop sound1
                    if (playbackstatus[1] == 0 && shortcliparray[1]==false) {
                        streamid[1] = soundPool.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1f)
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_playing)
                        playbackstatus[1] = 1
                    } else if (playbackstatus[1] == 0 && shortcliparray[1]==true){
                        streamid[1] = soundPool.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1f)
                    } else if (playbackstatus[1] == 1 ) {
                        soundPool.stop(streamid[1])
                        streamid[1] = soundPool.play(sound1, 1f, 1f, 0, -1, 1f)
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_looping)
                        playbackstatus[1] = 2
                    } else if (playbackstatus[1] == 2 ) {
                        soundPool.stop(streamid[1])
                        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_notplaying)
                        playbackstatus[1] = 0
                    }
                }
            }
```

I checked quite a lot of other posts, but I cannot get any further based on what I read. :(